# How to use design of reading XLSX file in a new one?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I try to modify some data in an excel. I read the file, and change the data, but if I save this xls with a new name, the whole design is deleted.

Is there a way to keep the design in the file?

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filepath);
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $xls = $reader->load($filepath);

    $xlsSheet = $xls->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $xlsSheet->getCell("A6")->getValue();

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xls, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);

    $objWriter->save('testfile.xlsx');
```

Comment: What do you imagine this line `$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);` does?

Comment: @MarkBaker in case of `$reader->setReadDataOnly(false) `, the following fatal error is the result. `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in ....PhpExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 856`

Comment: Then you need to look at something like cell caching to reduce memory usage, or increasing the memory that you make available to PHP

Comment: But setting read data only to true is telling PHP to read only the raw data from the spreadsheet file, and not to read any of the styling or formatting

Comment: @MarkBaker Now I have changed the `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` and use cell chaching `PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_in_memory` and ` memoryCacheSize ' => '50MB'` but it does not work. same problem.

Comment: `PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_in_memory` and `memoryCacheSize ' => '50MB'` is a pretty meaningless combination because it doesn't exist as a valid combination.... read the cell caching options/details and consider using n option other than simply telling PHPExcel to use it's default "use standard memory PHP memory for everything"